# Kotlin JpaRepository saves new empy object for an update

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

So I'm using spring boot and kotlin. When I post an object, I use the uuid to do a lookup if I have one in the database. If I do then I modify that one, otherwise use a new instance.

When I look in the database I see my updated version, and then a new empty row.

I can see the updated time stamp, and if I use the debugger to manipulate values it saves. however there's always a new row, with a new ID and all of the fields are empty

Service

```
@Service("claimService")
class ClaimService {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var billingCodeRepository: BillingCodeRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var claimRepository: ClaimRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var specialtyRepository: SpecialtyRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var doctorRepository: DoctorRepository

    fun saveClaim(submittedClaim: ClaimDto) {

        val existingClaim: Optional<Claim> = claimRepository.findById(submittedClaim.claim.uuid)
        if (existingClaim.isPresent)
        {
            convertClaimFromDto(submittedClaim, existingClaim.get())
        } else {
            val claim = Claim()
            convertClaimFromDto(submittedClaim, claim)
        }
    }

    fun convertClaimFromDto(submittedClaim: ClaimDto, claim: Claim)
    {

        claim.payProgram = submittedClaim.claim.payProgram
        claim.dxCode = submittedClaim.claim.dxCode
        claim.facility = submittedClaim.claim.facility
        claim.billingDate = DateUtil.convertDate(submittedClaim.claim.claimDate)
        claim.patient = convertPatientFromDto(submittedClaim.claim.patient)

        for(billingCode in submittedClaim.claim.billedCodes)
        {
            val billedCode: Optional<BillingCode> = billingCodeRepository.findById(billingCode.code)
            if (billedCode.isPresent)
            {
                val claimCode = BilledCodes()
                claimCode.billingCode = billedCode.get()
                claimCode.billed = billingCode.amountBilled
                claim.billedCodes.add(claimCode)
            }
        }

        //Test values
        val testDoc: Optional<ca.billingpro.billingcore.Domain.Doctor> = doctorRepository.findById(1)
        claim.doc = testDoc.get()
        claim.createdBy = "TestPoint"

        claimRepository.save(claim)
    }

    fun convertPatientFromDto(submittedPatient: ClaimDto.Claim.Patient): Patient
    {
        val patient = Patient()
        patient.DOB = DateUtil.convertDate(submittedPatient.DOB)
        patient.name = submittedPatient.name
        patient.ohipNo = submittedPatient.ohipNo
        patient.ohipVer = submittedPatient.ohipNo
        patient.sex = submittedPatient.sex
        return patient
    }

 }
```

claim

```
@Entity
data class Claim (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    var uuid: String = ""
    )
    {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    var claimNo: Long = 0

    var status: ClaimStatus = ClaimStatus.CREATED

    var billingDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.now()

    var lastUpdated: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()

    var facility: String = ""

    var payProgram: String = ""

    var createdAt:LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()

    var createdBy: String = ""

    var dxCode: String = ""

    var notes: String = ""

    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    var patient: Patient = Patient()

    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    var doc: Doctor = Doctor()

    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], mappedBy = "claim")
    var billedCodes: MutableList<BilledCodes> = mutableListOf<BilledCodes>()

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    fun updateClaim()
    {
        lastUpdated = LocalDateTime.now()
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
interface ClaimRepository : CrudRepository<Claim, String>
```

rows

```
5bdf8247-5c66-4a9e-9101-450588d5e6b8    2018-01-01  2   2018-08-03 20:41:03 TestPoint   1234    1234    2018-08-03 20:56:41 ""  HCP 0   1   47
a9200e84-643b-409a-9c44-2b69aa8a9823    2018-08-03  0   2018-08-03 20:56:41 ""  ""  ""  2018-08-03 20:56:41 ""  ""  0   23  46
16249817-6f4b-46df-a959-ec0595bb06d7    2018-01-01  0   2018-08-03 20:57:03 TestPoint   1234    1234    2018-08-03 20:57:03 ""  HCP 0   1   48
6799275b-e067-439e-aec1-2f9166e9b2ba    2018-08-03  0   2018-08-03 20:57:03 ""  ""  ""  2018-08-03 20:57:03 ""  ""  0   24  49
76c2fd49-5a92-4e3a-a8db-d882beb635e2    2018-01-01  0   2018-08-03 21:07:14 TestPoint   1234    1234    2018-08-03 21:07:14 ""  HCP 0   1   50
fec419d9-ae9d-4d53-a287-add14b1cd373    2018-08-03  0   2018-08-03 21:07:14 ""  ""  ""  2018-08-03 21:07:14 ""  ""  0   25  51
```

test function

```
@Component
class ApplicationStartup: ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>
{
    @Autowired
    lateinit var claimService: ClaimService
    override fun onApplicationEvent(event: ApplicationReadyEvent) {
        //var claimService: ClaimService = ClaimService()
        var testStr = "{\"claim\":{\"uuid\": \"5bdf8247-5c66-4a9e-9101-450588d5e610\",\"claimNo\": 123,\"status\": \"CREATED\",\"claimDate\": \"2018-01-01\",\"facility\": \"1234\",\"dxCode\": \"1234\",\"notes\": \"test notes\",\"payProgram\": \"HCP\",\"patient\": {\"name\": \"first last\",\"DOB\": \"1992-05-06\",\"ohipNo\": \"123456789\",\"verCode\": \"AA\",\"sex\": \"M\"},\"billedCodes\": [{\"code\": \"A001A\",\"amountBilled\": 19.21,\"amountPaid\": 0.0}]}}"
        val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
        val claimTest = mapper.readValue<ClaimDto>(testStr)
        claimService.saveClaim(claimTest)
    }
}
```

Comment: pls post the code of Claim.kt

Comment: I tired but SO complianed that it was mostly code...

Comment: pls format properly

Comment: @WilliMentzel sorry what's wrong with the formatting?

Comment: pls indent your code properly

Comment: @WilliMentzel all indendted.

Comment: in saveClaim.. are you sure that you are going into the if and not the else branch? if you indeed go into the if branch: what uuid does the claim have (use debugger).

Comment: @WilliMentzel I do. I checked the debugger and it does reach that branch. When I mdofiy the request not to hit that branch, it creates 2 new rows. One filled one empty. I'll put in the post what I mean by filled and empty

Comment: i think saveClaim is called twice, pls check that

Comment: Running through the debugger the line for the findbyid is only hit once. Looking through the project shows saveClaim only called once.

Comment: pls create a minimal example where the problem can be reproduced. all fluff aside

Comment: I mean beyond what's posted I just have the linked domain models, some json DTOs, and a single post endpoint. That's litterally my code at this point

Comment: create a single function which can reproduce the undesired behaviour, isolate it from the rest. run it with hard coded data.

Comment: @WilliMentzel so..... I added a function that will be done when startup is finished. It adds two rows to the DB, neither have that UUID.

When I go into the debugger. The correct claim with the UUID is getting passed to the function, and being modified. But the claim object that gets saved isnt....

Comment: So I have it now that it updates the correct one, but still creates a second one.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is in the way I did the mapping of the billing codes. Removing that relationship no longer did the duplicate save.

The relationships needed the @Transient flag and the mapping for the billing codes needed to have the mapped by